# Angularjs: how to move $index on top of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to move an item of my `ng-repeat` list in order to make it in first position.

I tried several things, but cannot seems to find a simple solution with orderby filter etc.

here's a fiddle :

http://jsbin.com/xavexepa/3/edit

the goal is to put for example tiger or zebra on the first position at the initialization of the ng-repeat, without sorting anything else

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Can show me your work which you have done so far either in JSBin or JSFiddle

Comment: you say you want to move something in ng-repeat, do you mean to sort the items in the list? something like [ui-sortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)? if not share some code so we can better help you.

Comment: @user256103 you wanna sort this list by some condition or it's random? did you tried to make custom field for sorting?

Comment: nope, i don't want to sort, just move a particular index to another position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to move items from one index to another here is an easy solution:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "name": "dog"
    },
    {
        "name": "cat"
    },
    {
        "name": "mouse"
    }
]

var move = function (array, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    array.splice(toIndex, 0, array.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0] );
    return array;
}

makeItemFirst = function (name){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].name == name){
            arr = move(arr, i, 0);
        }
    }
}

makeItemFirst("mouse");
```

Comment: Yes thanks that's what i want, but is there a way to do this with the orderBy ?